# Python: Import errors. Accessing method from other class

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I've got following problem: In my main tk window I have a button which opens a new Toplevel window. Once a button on the Toplevel window is clicked, a new element to a listbox should be added.

I keep getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MainWindow.py", line 4, in <module>
    from TopWindow import TopWindow
  File "TopWindow.py", line 4, in <module>
    import MainWindow
  File "MainWindow.py", line 4, in <module>
    from TopWindow import TopWindow
ImportError: cannot import name TopWindow
```

I believe the problem is that both classes import each other. However I am uncertain how to fix this. Any ideas?

Mainwindow.py:

```
from TopWindow import TopWindow

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, mainWindow):
        self.value = ''
        self.gui(mainWindow)
    def gui(self, mainWindow):
        top = TopWindow()
        button = tk.Button(optionFrame, text="Open TopWindow", command=top.import)
        ...

    def addtolistbox(self):
        ....


mainWindow = tk.Tk()
run = MainWindow(mainWindow)
mainWindow.mainloop()
```

TopWindow.py

```
import MainWindow
class TopWindow:
    def import(self):
        ....
        MainWindow.MainWindow().addtolistbox()
```

Comment: `def import(self):` i think it's your problem. it should be __init__()

Comment: Is the naming choice meant to be funny?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a circular import; when importing `MainWindow` from `TopWindow`, the `TopWindow` class is not yet defined, so the `TopWindow` module as seen by `MainWindow` doesn't have that attribute.

Postpone importing in the `TopWindow` class:

```
class TopWindow:
    def import(self):
        ....
        import MainWindow
        MainWindow.MainWindow().addtolistbox()
```

Next, you are creating a new copy of the `MainWindow` object each time; you probably want to access the singleton object created in `MainWindow.run` instead:

```
class TopWindow:
    def import(self):
        ....
        import MainWindow
        MainWindow.run.addtolistbox()
```

Comment: Thank you! That indeed fixes the import error. However, now I have a different problem. By calling  MainWindow.MainWindow().addtolistbox(), I create a new Mainwindow instead of just updating the list on the existing window. I don't want a new MainWindow created, but a function called within the MainWindow to update the existing one. How would I do that?

Comment: In addition, the new MainWindow isn't in the mainloop anymore. I'm getting a TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: @user3111516: Perhaps you wanted to use `MainWindow.run.addtolistbox()` instead? You already created your main window object in that module.